# LaTeX alignment in tables

Tags: tables, tabularx

I'm trying to create a custom environment that uses tables to align some stuff. I want the first column to be left-aligned, so I used the command `\tabularx{\textwidth}{ l X c X }`. This produces the expected result on the first `\item`, but the rest of the `\item`s are all right aligned. What am I doing wrong?

I have a custom class file `instructions.cls`

```
% Formal Instructions format

\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\LoadClass[10pt]{scrartcl}
\ProvidesClass{instructions}
              [2015/02/26 v1.0 Technical Instructions]

\RequirePackage[hmargin=0.5in,vmargin=0.5in]{geometry}
\RequirePackage{tabularx}
\RequirePackage{hyperref}

\hypersetup{
    bookmarks=true
}

\newcounter{StepListCounter}

\newenvironment{steplist} {
    \medskip
    \setcounter{StepListCounter}{1}
    \renewcommand\item[2]{
        \medskip
        {\textbf{\arabic{StepListCounter}}} & ##1 & & ##2 \\
        \stepcounter{StepListCounter}
    }

    \tabularx{\textwidth}{ r X c X }
} {
    \endtabularx
    \medskip
}
```

My tex file, `instructions.tex`:

```
\documentclass{instructions}

\begin{document}

\section*{Preparing the Parachute}

In this section, you will untangle the parachute and prepare it for the process of packing.

\begin{steplist}
    \item{Set the harness/container system on the ground with the shoulder
        harness toward the ground.}{}
    \item{Place the weight on the ground at the top of the harness.}{}
    \item{Place the rear lines in your right hand and the front lines in your
        left hand.}{}
    \item{Walk toward the parachute with the lines in your hand.}{}
    \item{Shake the parachute left \& right to remove as many creases as
        possible.}{}
\end{steplist}

\section*{Folding the Parachute}

These steps will guide you through organizing and folding the parachute so that
it can fit into the D-Bag and properly deploy.

\section*{Packing the Parachute in the D-Bag}

In the following section, you will will pack the folded parachute into the
D-Bag.

\section*{Securing the Lines}

In these steps, you will secure the lines to the straps on the outside of the D-Bag.

\section*{Packing the D-Bag in the Container}

You will pack the D-Bag into the container, keeping the lines organized so they
do not tangle.

\section*{Closing the Container}

In the following steps, you will be guided through closing the container around
the D-Bag so that it does not open prematurely.

\end{document}
```

And how it looks rendered:

[image: Imgur]

Comment: Hi! Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem. I'm actually quite sure that I see what is the problem, but without seeing your setup I can't say that 100%.

Comment: @yo' edited to add a full working example

Comment: If I run the code above the numbers are all aligned

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After relocating some  of lines,

```
\documentclass{Article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\newcounter{StepListCounter}
\renewcommand\item[2]{%
        \medskip\noindent
        {\textbf{\arabic{StepListCounter}}\stepcounter{StepListCounter}} & #1 & & #2 \\
    }
\newenvironment{steplist} {%
    \medskip
    \setcounter{StepListCounter}{1}%
    \tabularx{\textwidth}{l X c X }
} {
    \endtabularx
    \medskip
}
\begin{document}
\begin{steplist}
    \item{Set the harness/container system on the ground with the shoulder
        harness toward the ground.}{}
    \item{Place the weight on the ground at the top of the harness.}{}
    \item{Place the rear lines in your right hand and the front lines in your
        left hand.}{}
    \item{Walk toward the parachute with the lines in your hand.}{}
    \item{Shake the parachute left \& right to remove as many creases as
        possible.}{}
\end{steplist}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Still, I wouldn't recommend using an explicit `\vskip` in a table. The fact that it works seems like a miracle to me. ``\\[\medskipamount]`` may be better :-)

Comment: @yo' Fair point, miracles happens some times BTW ;-)

Comment: Why does moving the `\stepcounter` command before the `& #1 & & #2 \\ ` fix this?

Comment: @NateMara Because otherwise you put it at the beginning of the cell and it messes up something there :-)

Comment: Adding `\noindent` would be good. Also there is at least one spurious blank space (right after `\setcounter{StepListCounter}{1}`) which should be commented out.